# Delete Data from Nsdocument Directory

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can i delete data from `NSDocumentDirectory` which i have saved  using the following code.

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *fullFileName2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@nameArray", documentsDirectory];
 nameArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:fullFileName2];

 [nameArray addObject:nameField.text];
 [nameArray writeToFile:fullFileName2 atomically:NO];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

NSString *fullFileName2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@nameArray", documentsDirectory]; 

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:fullFileName2 error: NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *fullFileName2 = [nameArray objectAtIndex:0];
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:fullFileName2 error: NULL];
```

Comment: Where is your `nameArray` ? is it in your `DocumentDirectory` ?

Comment: See my new Edit.. and also check `[nameArray objectAtIndex:0]` should not be null..

Comment: I hope your `nameArray` is not nil after writing this line `nameArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:fullFileName2];` and if it is not nil then remove item from your first location of `nameArray` and then pass `nameArray` to tableView..